# shark does not show source code

Tags: iphone, symbols, shark

We are trying to run shark on our iphone application. However, in the analyzed samples it does not list any of our application function. All that is listed are the libraries and when we click on any of those, the assembly code is visible.
Most of the sites mention about 'Generate Debug Symbols' option when building the app; I am not able to find this option either. Instead I have enabled the 'Generate Profiling Information' option.
Can anyone please help as to how do I see my application functions and source code in the analyzed samples of Shark?

Comment: I have same problem. I hope somebody will be able to help us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compile it with for debugging (not just with symbols), see the shark manual.