# Shark does not show function names

Tags: iphone, xcode, shark

I want to use  shark to profile my application(I used it before and it worked fine), but now it does not show any function name. I have only Unknown Library and address[unknown] in symbol column. Some project parts are static libraries(compiled and linked in same project, with debug symbols on). Function names from standard lib or from other framework are shown.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you compile with debug symbols activated? Release builds have the symbols stripped and hence shark cannot show them.

Comment: (compiled and linked in same project, with debug symbols on)
Yes, I compiled with debug symbols activated

Comment: There's someone with the very same problem. Maybe it's a bug? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048086/shark-does-not-show-source-code